# Oracle find out delayed project with requirements with bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle

Table PROJECT

```
PROJECT     PJID     STARTDYA       ENDDAY         STATUS        PJINC
Lakers      P01      03/01/2021     04/01/2021     SExceed       Ken
Lakers      P03      04/01/2021     05/01/2021     NonExceed     John
Lakers      P04      02/01/2021     03/01/2021     NonExceed     Simon
Bulls       P05      09/01/2021     10/01/2021     EExceed       Billy
Bulls       P06      07/01/2021     08/01/2021     EExceed       Gary
Heat        P07      08/01/2021     09/01/2021     SExceed       Tim
Heat        P08      05/01/2021     06/01/2021     NonExceed     Mary
```

Table EMPLOYEE

```
Project    PJINC      WORKDATE         WORKHRS
Lakers     Ken        02/28/2021       3
Lakers     Ken        02/28/2021       3
Lakers     Ken        02/28/2021       6
Lakers     John       03/28/2021       12
Lakers     Simon      04/01/2021       2
Bulls      Billy      09/30/2021       3
Bulls      Billy      09/30/2021       7
Bulls      Gary       07/30/2021       1
Heat       Tim        01/16/2021       3
Heat       Mary       05/31/2021       5
```

Expected result

```
PJINC     PROJECT      PJID
Ken       Lakers       P01
Billy     Bulls        P05
```

Output criteria:

1. The SExceed should be earlier than the user set date (SETDATE). OR the EExceed should be earlier than the user set date (SETDATE). Depends on the STATUS is SExceed or EExceed. If STATUS is SExceed, then SExceed should be befeore the user set date (SETDATE). If STATUS is EExceed, then EExceed should be befeore the user set date (SETDATE).
2. The employee(PJINC) should be work more than 10 hours one day before the SExceed, EExceed date.
3. Assume the user set the (SETDATE) is 10/31/2021. Use Ken as an example. The PROJECT Lakers STATUS is SExceed, so we use STARTDYA to be the comparison to the user set date (SETDATE) and it is earlier than the user set date (10/31/2021). The pervious day of STARTDYA of PROJECT Lakers that Ken do is 02/28/2021, which is the pervious day of STARTDYA (03/01/2021). Also the total working hours (WORKHRS) of Ken is (3+3+6) which is = 12 and it is >= 10. SO Ken is in the output.
4. Assume the user set the (SETDATE) is 10/31/2021. Use Billy as an example. The PROJECT Bulls STATUS is EExceed, so we use ENDDAY to be the comparison to the user set date (SETDATE) and it is earlier than the user set date (10/31/2021). The pervious day of ENDDAY of PROJECT Bulls that Billy do is 09/30/2021, which is the pervious day of ENDDAY (10/01/2021). Also the total working hours (WORKHRS) of Billy is (3+7) which is = 10 and it is >= 10. SO Billy is in the output.

Below is my current idea

```
SELECT PJINC, PROJECT, PJID,
CASE WHEN STATUS = 'SExceed' THEN
     TO_DATE('10/31/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY') /* user set day should be here (bind variable)*/ > TO_DATE(STARTDYA, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
     WHEN STATUS = 'EExceed' THEN
     TO_DATE('10/31/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY') /* user set day should be here (bind variable)*/ > TO_DATE(ENDDAY, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
END as DelayProject
FROM PROJECT, EMPLOYEE
Where STATUS = 'SExceed' or STATUS = 'EExceed'
```

May I ask how to possible to code it to fulfill the requirements?

Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: Show what your expected output should be based on your sample data and explain why. Note the word DATE is a reserved word and should not be a column name. Why is data for john 31/03/2021 that doesn't match the format of other dates in your example

Comment: I just correct it, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Since I don't understand what you wrote tell me why Ken appears in your expected output and why Billy appears

Comment: I just update the output conditions.

Comment: Hope that it is more understandable.

Comment: Why employee table does not contain PJID column instead of PROJECT column?

Comment: I don't know either, they provided this data for me. This is also the difficulties to link with both tables.